# Why does git checkout from a bare repo delete instead of creating?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout, git-bare

This is kind of a weird one, and I apologize in advance if it doesn't have much application outside of my specific circumstances.  I am using git to manage my deployment packages by committing and tagging a set of generated files relating to the deployment and a submodule which points to the release code.  I am attempting to do a git checkout of this deployment tag from a bare repo on each machine into a different, empty directory.  The output I get indicates that it has deleted the files it should have created, and the work-tree directory remains empty afterward.

```
$ ls -al /var/www/test/
total 0

$ git --bare --work-tree=/var/www/test/ checkout my_tag
D   .gitmodules
D   generated.tgz
D   release
D   signatures.md5
HEAD is now at 8946ff5... Generated contents of deployment package.

$ ls -al /var/www/test/
total 0
```

I should state that both the commit referenced by my_tag and the tip of master have the same 4 files (though with different contents).  Which makes it all the stranger that the following procedure gets me 75% of the way there:

```
$ git --bare --work-tree=/var/www/test/ checkout master
D   .gitmodules
Previous HEAD position was 8946ff5... Generated contents of deployment package.
Switched to branch 'master'

$ ls -al /var/www/test/
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 17 17:00 generated.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 17 17:00 release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 17 17:00 signatures.md5

$ git --bare --work-tree=/var/www/test/ checkout my_tag
D   .gitmodules
(---- git's warning about detached HEAD state cut ----)
HEAD is now at 8946ff5... Generated contents of deployment package

$ ls -al /var/www/test/
total 4624
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2103765 Oct 17 17:02 generated.tgz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Oct 17 17:00 release
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2614883 Oct 17 17:02 signatures.md5
```

The thing is, "release" is a git submodule, and I can't init or update it without .gitmodules, so 75% of the way there still isn't good enough.

One solution to this problem would be to simply clone the repo anew every time I deploy, and maybe I'll go that way if nobody can suggest a better solution.  But ideally I'd like to keep one bare repo on each machine and checkout from that to a new work-tree each time.  Can anybody tell me what's going on here?

For reference, I'm using Git 1.8.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that `checkout` is comparing the desired revision (`my_tag`, `master`) against what's in `HEAD` in the `--bare` repo.  (And the `--bare` argument is doing nothing.)  So with `my_tag`, it says you're already in detached `HEAD` mode and on the desired rev—i.e., it should not change `HEAD`—and looks into the target directory, `/var/www/test/`, and sees that the files have been removed and gives you the `D` status for each.  It assumes they were there because of the index (see below).

When you switch to `checkout master`, it figures: OK, you're moving from this detached-`HEAD` to `master`, it updates `HEAD` and checks out the changed files.  But `.gitmodules` is the same in `my_tag` and `head`, so that one remains `D`eleted.

If you use `checkout -f`, it will assume it should replace the missing files.

Git also has the bad habit :-) of using `$GIT_DIR/index` to record what it is doing with the checkout, as well as `$GIT_DIR/HEAD`.  This leads to left-behind files when files are removed from the thing you're trying to deploy.  If the target directory is emptied out before doing a `checkout -f` that should be OK though.  (Alternatively, set `GIT_INDEX_FILE` in the environment, naming a file you keep along with each unique deployment.  I have not experimented with this but it should work well.)

Comment: Thanks for your response torek, this helped somewhat but I'm still missing .gitmodules in the work tree.  I assume this is because the file has never changed in the lifetime of the repo, and so no checkout will consider it a changed file worth creating?

(FYI, the work tree dir will always be empty, it is created during this deployment process.)

Comment: Actually, I was wrong.  I did get .gitmodules with that checkout, I was just using an 'll' alias which on this server doesn't show me hidden files.  Sorry about that!  And thanks for your answer, this was exactly what I needed.  Take care!